# A problem about arc, angle in circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Let $M$ is the midpoint of the arc ${AB}$ of the circle $(C)$, $E$ is a point of the arc $MB$. Let $H$ is the perpendicular projection of $M$ on $AE$. Prove that: $AH=HE+EB$.

i tried to draw more line but get stuck on HE, they just said E is an point on the arc MB.

Can anyone show me some ideas for this proof? this is a problem when i study about arc. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Show please your attempts

Comment: Are you sure this statement is true.
It should hold for any position of E,

Comment: i tried to draw more line but get stuck on $HE$, they just said $E$ is an point on the arc $MB$.

Comment: I tried to draw on an software, it is true with all the point $E$ on the arc $MB$, so the statement should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the figure below, where $AE$ has been produced to $B'$, so that $EB \cong EB'$.

[image]

1. Observe that $\angle MEB$ and $\angle MAB$ are supplementary. Moreover, $\angle MEA\cong\angle MBA\cong \angle MAB$.
2. By means of 1., demonstrate that $\triangle MEB \cong \triangle MEB'$ (SAS criterion).
3. Use 2. to show that $\triangle MAB'$ is isosceles, implying $AH \cong HB'$. And the thesis follows immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\measuredangle ACM=\measuredangle MCB=\alpha$ and $\measuredangle MEC=\beta.$

Thus, $$AH=AM\cos\measuredangle MAE=2R\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2},$$
$$EH=EM\cos\measuredangle MEA=2R\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}$$ and
$$EB=2R\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}.$$
Id est, we need to prove that:
$$\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\beta}{2}=\sin\frac{\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: ya, it completely proved by trigonometry funtion when expand $\sin\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)$. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $\angle AMO = \alpha$, $\angle MOE = \beta $ and $r$ be the radius of the circle. Then,

$$AH = AM\cos\frac{\beta}2 = 2r\cos\alpha\cos\frac{\beta}2$$

Note that $y=180-2\alpha$. Then,

$$HE = AE - AH  = 2r\sin\frac{y+\beta}2 - AH
=2r\cos(\alpha - \frac{\beta}2)- 2r\cos\alpha\cos\frac{\beta}2=2r\sin\alpha\sin\frac{\beta}2$$

Also, note that $x = 180 - 2\alpha - \beta$. Then,

$$EB = 2r \sin\frac x2 = 2r\cos(\alpha + \frac{\beta}2)$$

Therefore,

$$HE + EB = 2r\sin\alpha\sin\frac{\beta}2 + 2r\cos(\alpha + \frac{\beta}2)= 2r\cos\alpha\cos\frac{\beta}2=AH$$